# Creating generic callback without std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, c++17, std-function

I have a C-style interface callback function and I would like to write a C++ wrapper
for it which can accept anything like a lambda, function object, plain function or a class member function. But I want to do this **without** std::function ! I've read that std::function is a pretty heavy construct (it is stateful and contains a couple of type erasures inside).. Besides, I do not like the idea of using std::bind when I want to provide a class member function callback.

So what I came up with is a templated generic callback function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

// this is our C-style function callback we would like to wrap
using CallbackC = void(void *, int);

// simulate an asynchronous task 
void performTaskAsync(void* data, CallbackC c)
{
    int rnd = rand() % 13;
    std::thread t([rnd, data, c]() {
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
         if (c != nullptr)
             c(data, rnd);
    });
    t.detach();
}

struct CppIntefaceWrapper
{
    template < class Invokable, class... This >
    using Tuple = std::tuple< std::decay_t<Invokable>, This...>;

    template < class Invokable, class... This >
    void execTask(Invokable&& callback, This&&... args) {

        using InvokableTyp = std::decay_t<Invokable>;
        std::cerr << "type: " << typeid(Invokable).name() << std::endl;

        static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<InvokableTyp, This..., int>,
                "Incorrect function object provided!");

        void* ptr = nullptr;
        if constexpr (sizeof...(This) == 0) {
            if constexpr (!std::is_class_v<InvokableTyp>) 
                // function pointer: cast to (void *) directly
                ptr = static_cast<void*>(callback);
            else 
                // lambdas and functors: we have to take the address of the reference object..
                ptr = static_cast<void*>(&callback);
        } 
        else {
            // pointer to member function : have to allocate additional storage :((
            auto bunny = new Tuple< Invokable, This...>(callback, std::forward<This>(args)...);
            ptr = static_cast<void*>(bunny);
        }
        performTaskAsync(ptr, &callbackStatic< InvokableTyp, This...>);
    }

private:

    template < class Invokable, class... This >
    static void callbackStatic(void *ptr, int result) {

        std::cerr << "callback type: " << typeid(Invokable).name() << std::endl;

        if constexpr (sizeof...(This) == 0) {
            if constexpr (!std::is_class_v<Invokable>) { // this is a branch for pointer to function
                auto func = (Invokable)ptr;
                std::invoke(func, result);
            }
            else {  // this is a branch for lambdas and Functors
                auto func = (Invokable *)ptr;
                std::invoke(*func, result);
            }
        } 
        else { // invoke member function callback
            auto bunny = (Tuple< Invokable, This...> *)ptr;
            auto [func, rest] = *bunny;
            delete bunny;
            std::invoke(func, rest, result);
        }
    }
};

void plainFuncRaw(int i) {
    std::cerr << "----------------- plain function raw: " << i << std::endl;
}

void plainFuncPtr(int i) {
    std::cerr << "----------------- plain function by pointer: " << i << std::endl;
}

struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int i) {
        std::cerr << "----------------- operator(): " << i << std::endl;
    }
    void funcPtr(int i) {
        std::cerr << "----------------- member func by pointer: " << i << std::endl;
    }
    void funcRef(int i) {
        std::cerr << "----------------- member func by reference: " << i << std::endl;
    }
    std::array< uint8_t, 1024> uu{};
};

int main(void)
{
    CppIntefaceWrapper ww;
    auto lambda = [](int i) {
        std::cerr << "----------------- lambda: " << i << std::endl;
    };

    Functor ff;
    ww.execTask(plainFuncRaw);
    ww.execTask(&plainFuncPtr);

    ww.execTask(ff);
    ww.execTask(lambda);

    ww.execTask(&Functor::funcRef, std::ref(ff));
    ww.execTask(&Functor::funcPtr, &ff);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is a program output:

```
type: void __cdecl(int)
type: void (__cdecl*)(int)
type: struct Functor
type: class <lambda_c22a344f599f4a82c6790074b727fb50>
type: void (__cdecl Functor::*)(int) __ptr64
type: void (__cdecl Functor::*)(int) __ptr64
callback type: class <lambda_c22a344f599f4a82c6790074b727fb50>
----------------- lambda: callback type: void (__cdecl*)(int)
----------------- plain function by pointer: 7
callback type: void (__cdecl Functor::*)(int) __ptr64
----------------- member func by reference: 7
callback type: void (__cdecl*)(int)
----------------- plain function raw: 2
callback type: void (__cdecl Functor::*)(int) __ptr64
----------------- member func by pointer: 7
6
callback type: struct Functor
----------------- operator(): 3
```

So basically, it seems to work fine for all required callback types..
But the implementation is quite messy - it has a bunch of
'if constexpr' expressions inside and also I have to allocate a block of dynamic memory with operator 'new' in order to call a class member function callback.

Perhaps somebody has better ideas how to improve this implementation or maybe there is already an available solution ?

Comment: There's really no reason to use `std::bind` now that we have lambdas.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this example what you want it to accomplish.  If you just want to use it immediately (e.g. pass it to std::thread), then there is no need for std::function, or any sort of type erasure.  If you want to put it onto a data structure for later processing, and you want the reader to be unaware of the underlying type, then you need the type erasure.  Once you get to the point of handling all of the edge cases, you might find `std::function` is about right

Comment: _"I do not like the idea of using std::bind when I want to provide a class member function callback."_. You may discover that a lambda is more commonly used fo this case, e.g.: `[ff]{ ff(); }`

Comment: @MooingDuck: nope, apart from std::function, my callback function is compile-time. It does not use type erasure and dynamic casts.. Yes, basically I could call user-provided std::function callback my callbackStatic() to forward it to the user

Comment: @pem: But that means the thing that stores the callback has to know the callback type... actually that's probably fine for your case. Makes sense.

Comment: @DrewDormann: yes, of course, one could use lambda to wrap a class member function callback and then give it to std::function.. but then you have two indirections: std::function -> lambda -> class member function

Comment: @DaveS: the idea is, say, we have a software library which exposes a C-style callback function pointer. I would like to wrap it into a C++ interface so that the user can call it with any possible callback type. Yes, to store a callback function you can either use std::function with type erasure or use templates to construct the callback type - this is what I am trying to achive

Comment: @pem: "*It does not use type erasure and dynamic casts..*" `std::function` doesn't use dynamic casts either. Your code is just as heavy-weight as `std::function`, since it dynamically allocates memory. Indeed, several `function` implementations have small object optimization, so in some cases, yours allocates memory where `function` would not.

Comment: *which can accept anything like a lambda* ... *std::function is a pretty heavy construct (it is stateful*. Lambdas can also have state, so to deal with all lambdas you need it too. Same for functors.

Comment: @NicolBolas: yes, my implementation allocates dynamic memory only in one case: when the user wants to call a class member function. BUT: std::function *cannot* be used with a class member function directly: one either has to use it with ugly std::bind() or wrap it in a lambda function (which is another level of indirection). Btw, I only need to store a pointer to an object in ad dynamic mem block, so it's a good idea, probably I can use a placement new instead

Comment: @super: sorry, I did not get your point: yes there are mutable lambdas which are stateful but I don't care about this.. My wrapper can invoke mutable lambdas as good as other functor types

Comment: @pem: "*std::function cannot be used with a class member function directly*" Nonsense; it can be given a member pointer. *However*, if you do so, the function signature must start with a pointer/reference to the class type. You want to map the desired function signature to a different signature from the member pointer; that's where your allocation comes from.

Comment: @pem: It should also be noted that your mechanism doesn't have to have storage because it *relies* on the outside world maintaining the storage for the callable. That's a usability weakness compared to `std::function`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: sorry, I've mistaken: yes you can initialize std::function with a class member function but then of course it won't be compatible with you callback signature anymore: suppose, your CPPWrapper accepts only std::function<void(int)>. The question is how would one implement such a CPPWrapper with std::function ? Probably one would have to store a vector of std::functions inside ?..  I'll extend my code for demonstration. Yes, I rely on external storage of the callable, that's probably weak if one gives it a local lambda function

Comment: In order to realize such a CPPWrapper with std::function - the only idea comes to my mind is to maintain an std::list<std::function<void(int)>> inside CPPWrapper (which should be mutex-protected in case it's used with multiple threads). Then, whenever we get the callback, we have to go over this list and erase an item corresponding to that particular callback, ugly.. (that's in case if function callbacks can come unordered, i.e. have different execution times)

Comment: @NicolBolas: you know that there is also a proposal for std::function_ref which acts like a non owning lightweight function wrapper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0792r3.html#motivating-example.  
That’s somehow similar to what I have written.. For instance, std::function cannot wrap a lambda with closure which refers to a local variable, have a look at the examine in the link above